# Does Hololens support Wifi Direct?

Tags: android, windows, wireless, wifi-direct, hololens

I am about to make a Hololens software that uses some wireless connection to interact with an Android mobile phone. Do you know does Hololens support Wifi Direct? If Hololens does not support Wifi Direct, can you tell what connection technologies can be alternatively used?

Comment: Is there a specific reason you are not connecting your phone and hololens to the same wifi network and using that to communicate between the two devices?

Comment: I think that Hololens does not support Wifi-Direct, but there can be used bluetooth (I didn't know how to use it before): https://www.gamedev.net/resources/_/technical/virtual-and-augmented-reality/gps-on-the-microsoft-hololens-r4497

Answer (score 1):

At this point HoloLens doesn't support WifiDirect. Soon HoloLens updated version is going to be released and hopefully that version will have this(not yet officially confirmed). 
However for now you can use BLE or use Mobile WifiDirect to create connection between devices.