# Is it possible to make a direct connection, by WiFi or Bluetooth, between two Hololens?

Tags: uwp, bluetooth, wifi, hololens

I am able to make two apps on two Hololens communicate through the same WiFi hotspot (UWP app developed in C#/Unity, communicating in UDP).

And now, I want to be able to do the same thing, let say, in the middle of the desert: no WiFi, no router...

I couldn't find a way to configure the WiFi into a ad hoc connection, or create a hotspot from a Hololens. Is this possible? Has somebody ever done it?

Maybe it is possible to do so with Bluetooth?

I am willing to do any kind of needed development, but I don't know where to start, or if the hardware even allow what I need...

Thanks in advance

Comment: This sounds like WiFi direct, which seems to not be implemented yet for hololens.  The comments on a Wifi Direct Hololens question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42674149/does-hololens-support-wifi-direct) suggest an alternative using bluetooth, which sounds to me like it should work between two hololenses.  What you want to achieve certainly seems possible.

Comment: Yes, it feels possible to me too, but I haven't found a way yet. It seems like I have to delve into Bluetooth...

Comment: @Fumidu If you ever found a solution I would love to know, esp. if your application is bandwidth intensive.  At this point I am hoping the upcoming hardware revision implements WiFi Direct or similar...

Comment: @eclarkso Sorry, I did not find any solution. I ended up using a very small, easily transportable, wifi router.

Answer (score 0):

Since HoloLens devices run UWP Apps, you can use the [RemoteSystem APIs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/connected-apps-and-devices) to communicate between two devices connected via a variety of methods.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but the question is about how to connect two devices, not how to communicate once they are connected.

Comment: The article outlines how to discover remote devices and connect to them as well. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/remote-sessions

Comment: You are talking application or session layer (layer 5-7 OSI). But first, I need network layer to be established (layer 3 OSI). There is no way to create a remote session to a device that is not connected to the same network.

Comment: You mentioned Bluetooth - which isn't a network layer - you can create the remote session connection using the Remote Systems API via Bluetooth with devices on different networks.

Comment: Indeed, bluetooth is more or less a physical layer, and that's the thing : Quote from [RemoteSystem APIs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/connected-apps-and-devices) `Devices can be connected proximally through Bluetooth and wireless, or remotely through the cloud`. Existing connection is a prerequisite to use this API. I don't have this prerequisite. My question is : "How to connect two hololens with no external equipment in between?". Or did I miss something?

Comment: Have you looked at the Sharing example in the Mixed Reality Toolkit? https://github.com/Microsoft/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity/blob/master/Assets/HoloToolkit/Sharing/README.md

Comment: Yes I did. I build my own app that allows collaboration between two hololens. It works fine when the two hololens are connected to the same wifi network, aka, there is a physical wifi router in the same room as the hololens, and all the data is going from hololens 1 to the router then to the hololens 2. Now my question is: how to get rid of this intermediate physical wifi router?